# OneToMany relationship does not store entity field

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, relationship

When saving my entities, child entities that work through the `@OneToMany` relationship are not saved to their tables. I can’t understand what’s the matter.

Employee:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "EMPLOYEE", schema = PUBLIC)
public class Employee {

private String name;

private String lastname;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "employee", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
List<EmployeePhoneNumber> employeePhoneNumbers = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

EmployeePhoneNumber:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EMPLOYEE_PHONES", schema = PUBLIC)
public class EmployeePhoneNumber {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(allocationSize = 1, name = "SEQ_EMPLOYEE_PHONES", schema = PUBLIC,
            sequenceName = "EMPLOYEE_PHONES_ID_SEQ")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "SEQ_EMPLOYEE_PHONES", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id", referencedColumnName = "id",
            nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Employee employee;

    @Column(name = "PHONE_NUMBER", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String phoneNumber;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "NUMBER_TYPE", nullable = false)
    private PhoneNumberType phoneNumberType;
}
```

How I set those fields and then save the entity:

```
        EmployeePhoneNumber workPhone = new EmployeePhoneNumber();
        workPhone.setPhoneNumber(workPhone);
        workPhone.setPhoneNumberType(PhoneNumberType.WORK_PHONE);

        EmployeePhoneNumber mobilePhone = new EmployeePhoneNumber();
        mobilePhone.setPhoneNumber(mobilePhone);
        mobilePhone.setPhoneNumberType(PhoneNumberType.MOBILE_PHONE);

        EmployeePhoneNumber corporatePhone = new EmployeePhoneNumber();
        corporatePhone.setPhoneNumber(corporatePhoneNumber);
        corporatePhone.setPhoneNumberType(PhoneNumberType.CORPORATE_PHONE);

        List<EmployeePhoneNumber> employeePhoneNumbers = employee.getEmployeePhoneNumbers();
        employeePhoneNumbers.add(workPhone);
        employeePhoneNumbers.add(mobilePhone);
        employeePhoneNumbers.add(corporatePhone);

        employee.setEmployeePhoneNumbers(employeePhoneNumbers);

        employeeRepository.save(employee);
```

Upon completion of the method, I do not have a single error, everything works out correctly, only the tables are not filled - why?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must also set the Employee reference in EmployeePhoneNumber because Hibernate will use this to save it.

```
workPhone.setEmployee(employee);
mobilePhone.setEmployee(employee);
corporatePhone.setEmployee(employee);
```

The best solution would be to create an addEmployeePhoneNumber method on the Employee like this:

```
 public void addEmployeePhoneNumber(EmployeePhoneNumber phoneNumber) {
     phoneNumber.setEmployee(this);
     employeePhoneNumbers.add(phoneNumber);
 }
```

That way you will not forget to set both sides of the relationship.

Comment: A good suggestion... if a Set was used instead of a List or a specific check was built-in to make sure no duplicate entries are added to the list through this convenience method.

Comment: @Gimby The duplicate will be checked by the database anyway. And yes a set would be helpful but not necessary